# Why is Ichi a common name for a blind person?

Tags: names

I was watching a Japanese movie and incidentally it is mentioned that Ichi is a common name given to a blind person. Why would that be?

Comment: Is it possible to include the full context of the dialog? What's the name of the movie? Transcribing the line in question and relevant surrounding lines is always helpful in these kinds of questions. Even if someone can answer the question without the context, it should always be included in case it's necessary. The question, as worded, assumes what was stated is factual, and I have no idea what the answer would be myself, but there are plenty of reasons one could imagine where it's not factual and there is some language-related explanation for the line. (a joke, a pun, a reference, etc.)

Comment: There is a movie called "Ichi" about a blind women, and the famous Zatoichi series about a blind sword master, but they might themselves already use that stereotype and did not create it.

Comment: @mic Both of those are just examples of the stereotype. You can find it in books too. The question is why blind people are stereotypically named "Ichi".

Comment: Let's speculate: The people with ichi in their names are the firstborns. There are and where (in history) probably as many blind people in the group of the firstborns as in the group of the secondborns, etc. But compared to other blind ones the firstborns had the best chance to get family resources i.e. education (maybe in religion), even if blind. So the blind firstborns are the ones that had a chance to become remarkable, famous and be remembered. The other blind ones may just have lived in some hut at the village border and became forgotten.

Comment: I gave this question a downvote based on the lack of context. I wanted to wait to give a chance for the context to be added. If it gets added, I would remove the downvote.